# "Бухта-барахта"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Интересует происхождение этого выражения. Имеет ли оно отношение к мору и, если да, то как появилось в языке и почему означает "без подготовки", "ни с того, ни с сего"?

Comment: "отношение к мору" или к морю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то словари дают только одну форму родительного падежа: "с бухты-барахты". 
Я думаю, что это от глаголов бухаться и барахтаться. Может и в море, но не обязательно. 
И то и другое вызывает очевидное ощущение неподготовленности действия.
Может и ошибаюсь, но с раннего детства поводов усомниться в такой этимологии у меня не было.

Что до моря, то у нескольких заливчиков (самый известный - в районе Кабардинки в Геленджике, если не ошибаюсь, это устье реки Кабардинка), носящих это гордое имя, оно безусловно вторично.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, оборот  "**с бухты-барахты**" (неодобр.) образован от глаголов *бухнуться* и *барахтаться*, характеризующих чьи-л. неожиданные и беспомощные действия. В речи шутливо ассоциируется с вымышленным наименованием бухты *Барахты* (А.К.Бирих и др. Русская фразеология. Историко-этимологический словарь)

Answer (score 1):

оборот "с бухты-барахты" образован из слов "бухта" - свернутый кольцами канат (на палубе судна или на причале), и "барахтаться" - плескаться в воде. Моряки в портах демонстрировали крутость, залезая на бухту каната, как на тумбу, и прыгая с нее в воду с шумом и брызгами.

Comment: Будет здорово, если вы дополните ответ источником или укажете, что это ваша собственная версия (кстати, хорошая, похоже на правду).